# .Net Core Identity - Storing fullname, address and etc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

Where can I find information about the pros and cons (from a performance and coding perspective) of using the methods below to store user info such as firstname, lastname, address and etc using AspNetCore.Identity.

1. Adding properties to a class that inherits the IdentityUser class
   (Adding field to the AspNetUsers table)
2. Adding a reference to a another class from a class that inherits the
   IdentityUser class (adding a reference to a new db table in the
   AspNetUsers table)
3. Use claims

Comment: Unless you follow a certain architectural pattern, you  can put it in any place you want. Also please use the correct tags. [tag:asp.net-mvc] is for old MVC webstack (MVC1-6), **NOT** for ASP.NET Core MVC.. Also look for a more suitable title, your title has no connection to the actually body of the question at all...

Comment: @Tseng Thanks for the edit. Your comment  seems off topic. You seem to have copy/pasted the same comment to my post as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763976/where-should-i-put-custom-classes-in-asp-net-core-project/43764711#43764711.

Comment: Tired of typing the same thing every time, when editing the tags :P