# Where should I put custom classes in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have some utility functions and want to create classes named Utility for these functions, so that I can use these class function in more than one controllers.

So where can I put these class in my folder structure in `ASP.NET Core 1.1` project, and how can I access then?

Comment: Unless you follow a certain architectural pattern, you  can put it in any place you want. Also please use the correct tags. [tag:asp.net-mvc] is for old MVC webstack (MVC1-6), **NOT** for ASP.NET Core MVC

Comment: I would put them to Services folder

Comment: @Alex Does putting them in Services folder require `Dependency Injection` etc? What is the significance/advantages of placing them in Service folder?

Comment: not required, but can be useful. It's just logical to put utilities in services. As already said, you can put them where you want, you can create folder Util for example. I put repository into Services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Tseng mentioned you can place them anywhere but usually you will not want to place them in the `wwwroot` hierarchy. :-)

Accessing them is as simple as specifying them by namespace or including the right using statement to the namespace they live in.  I personally keep most of my custom classes in separate library projects but for the ones I want in the actual asp.net core project I keep them in a folder called `Code`, but you can name it whatever feels right for your project.

Here is one example from a project I'm currently working on.  It shows how I have organized subfolders under the `Code` folder.

[image]